# Converting a Python Dictionary into Associative Array for PHP

Tags: php, python, python-2.7

I wrote a sorting algorithm in python.

It returns a Python Dictionary object.

How do i get the dictionary from Python into my PHP code as an associative arr ?

Will I have to write the whole sorting algorithm again in PHP?

Comment: A sorting algorithm that returns a Python dictionary? I'd like to see that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Serializing to JSON would be the simplest thing to do:

python:

```
import json
fp = open('/tmp/mydict', 'w+')
json.dump(myDict, fp)
```

then in php:

```
$myDict = json_decode(file_get_contents('/tmp/mydict'));
```

But re sorting - dictionaries in python are not ordered.
if you want to save it ordered and load ordered, save a python list and load a php array.

Comment: JFYI, you inverted the order of the parameters: it's `json.dump(myDict,fp)` Still a working solution

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is save the Dictionary Object as `json` or `xml` in Python, then use `json_decode` or `simple_xml` in PHP to load it as array or object

You need no sorting algorithm ... `PHP` has a lot of them

Answer (score 0):

Just use usort function: your comparer can be passed to it.
http://php.net/usort